# Using Tumblr's block elements in externally hosted CSS

Tags: css, themes, tumblr

I'm having problems using Tumblr's custom variables functionality with externally hosted CSS.

**Background**
Tumblr themes are written as a single page of html with all CSS stored in `<style>` tags in the document `<head>`

Tumblr allows user-defined data to be stored in variable of your naming, wrapped in curly braces. These can then be applied in the CSS. An example might be a color hex code being attached to `{color:BackgroundColour}` which can then be used in place of a #value in the CSS. (More [info](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#appearance-options))

When a browser renders the page the data stored in `{color:BackgroundColor}` is returned as the hex code and everything is ok.

**Problem**
To make theme development easier I am hosting my CSS externally and linking in the `<head>`
When the page renders, my custom variables are returned as the as they are written in the CSS, rather than pulling the attached value.

So the page renders:

```
#header{
width: 600px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
background-color:{color:BackgroundColor};  
}
```

Instead of:

```
#header{
width: 600px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
background-color: #dedede;  
}
```

This only happens when the CSS is linked from external hosting. Is their a way that I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my limited understanding of the tumblr templating engine I do not believe this is possible with a remotely hosted css file.  All of the variables declarations are rendered server side and served up to the client with the correct syntax.  No matter how you inject your externally hosted css file it will be to late as the server already rendered the content.

The only compramise I could see working would be to split up your css file to selectors that require the variables and ones that do not.

Example:
style block contained in the tumblr page.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #header{
        background-color:{color:BackgroundColor};  
    }
</style>
```

Externally hosted file:

```
#header{
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

That way you can fulfill your requirement of an externally hosted css file but also utilize the tumblr engine.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Having done further reading it looks like until Tumblr make some changes at their end having the CSS split so that all user-defined variables are held on the page while everything else is hosted externally is the way to go.